# Not getting the nav parent-page active when I'm in child-page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django

Parent page is good like so:

[image]

When I click on the child page it does not behave like parent does:

[image]

Although I have the **base.html** in child page it wont show as wished.

I have tried several solutions with no luck so hopefully you can guide me in the right way.

Still a newbie and appreciate all your help, folks!

---

**EDIT:** added more html

base.html

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('li.active').removeClass('active');
   $('a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
</script>

   <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Prociation</a>

              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="notifications" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="Notifications">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
              </a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li  class="active"><a href="{% url 'member_overview' %}">
                 {% trans 'Members' %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'docs' %}">
                {% trans 'Documents' %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'articles' %}">
               {% trans 'Articles' %}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'pics' %}">
                {% trans 'Pictures' %}</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

member_overview.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
 ...
 <div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'member_signup' %}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        {% trans 'New Member' %}
    </a>
 </div>
```

### ...

member/urls.py (if it helps)

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^member_overview/$', views.member_overview.as_view(), name='member_overview'),
        url(r'^member_signup/$', views.member_signup, name='member_signup'),
        ...
]
```

Comment: What output did you get when you've console [location.pathname]? on your browser

Comment: I'm getting the pathname as described above images.
**["/member_overview/"]** and **["/member_signup/"]**

Comment: Did you've inspect the <ul> element to check the value of each of your <a>tags [href] attributes?

Comment: Yup, the pathnames are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because you've set each of your [a] tags [href] have a backslash (e.g '/') suffix value at the end of your [location.pathname] value.

You may need to add a backslash (e.g '/') for each of your [a] tags [href] value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('a[href="' + location.pathname + '/"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Hope this helps for your case

**Edit** : You might need to have a condition if the user access the 'member_signup' link

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('a[href="' + location.pathname + '/"]').closest('li').addClass('active');

    if (location.pathname === '/member_signup') {
       $('a[href="member_overview"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: No, sorry, it didn't work. Even the nav parent-page didn't work. Thank you for given it a try =)

Comment: Can you update your question and add additional info on your [html]?

Comment: Edited **base.html**. Let me know if you need anything else =)

Comment: Let me verify this. If you access ('/member_signup') link, when you've inspect element on your browser, did you see [active] class in that [a] tag?

Comment: No [active] class in ('/member_signup'). You think that may be the problem?
It only says **<li class>** while the parent says **<li class="active">**

Comment: YOU ARE AN ANGEL!!! I just had to adjust the url to "django-url-way (python)" in order to make it function. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! =D